# Random Process, how do I understand this?

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables

I think I have little difficulty in understanding the "Random Process". Here is a definition taken from Oppenheim's book.

> In Section 7.3 we deﬁned a random variable X as a function that maps
>   each outcome   of a probabilistic experiment to a real number. In a
>   similar manner, a real-valued   CT or DT random process, X(t) or X[n]
>   respectively, is a function that maps   each outcome of a
>   probabilistic experiment to a real CT or DT signal respectively,
>   termed the realization of the random process in that experiment. For
>   any ﬁxed   time instant t = t0 or n = n0, the quantities X(t0) and
>   X[n0] are just random   variables. The collection of signals that can
>   be produced by the random process is   referred to as the ensemble of
>   signals in the random process.

So, in other word, can I say that, $X(t)$ (for $0<=t<=T) $    is just a collection of random variables that $X(0)$ is a single random variables, and $X(1)$ is another random variable?  And could I say that, each $X(t_0)$ (where $t_o$ is just a number)is a sample taken from the PDF of $X$, and that each $X(t_o)$ is a realization of the random process?

I also have trouble trying to match it up with the matlab example, in which we run the 'normrand' command.

```
R = normrnd(mu,sigma,m,n,...)
```

For instance, if I run

```
n2 = normrnd(0,1,[1 5])
n2 =
  0.0591  1.7971  0.2641  0.8717  -1.4462
```

Can I say that n2 is just a random process that each element of n2 array, n2[1], n2[2], n2[3], n2[4], n2[5], they are just samples taken from the normal gaussian distribution, and here, we are having 5 realizations of this gaussian process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume you have a measurable space $(\Omega, \mathscr{F})$. Then, as you mentioned, a random variable is a measurable function:

$$ X: \Omega \to \mathbb R$$

On the other hand, a stochastic process, maps $\Omega$ to a function space. For example, the space of continuous functions on $[0,1]$, namely $C[0,1]$. So $X$ would be a function:

$$ X: \Omega \to C[0,1] $$

In other words, for $\omega \in \Omega$, $X(\omega)$ is a continuous function in $[0,1]$. Now, for fixed $t_0 \in [0,1]$, define the projection

$$\pi_{t_0}: C[0,1] \to \mathbb R, \pi_{t_0}(f) = f(t_0)$$

Then for each $t_0$, you get a new random variable $X_{t_0}: \Omega \to \mathbb R$ defined as $X_{t_0}(\omega) = \pi_{t_0}(X(\omega)) = X(\omega)(t_0)$.

In other words your first statement is correct, $(X_t, t \in [0,1])$ is a family of random variables and e.g. $X_1$ is a single random variable. Notice that I have tried to separate the way I write the index, because I think this might have caused your confusion in part. Often you will see a stochastic process written as a function $\Omega \times [0,1] \to \mathbb R $, but for me it is more intuitive to think of a realization of the stochastic process as just being a function.

So to answer your other questions: $X_{t_0}$ is not a realization of the stochastic process, it is the projection of the stochastic process, and it is a random variable. Also $X_{t_0}$ is not a sample taken from the pdf of $X$. Indeed, if we also attach a measure on the measurable space $(\Omega,\mathscr{F})$, then $X$ defines a measure on $C[0,1]$, while the random variable $X_{t_0}$ defines a measure on $\mathbb R$.

Similarly, a discrete stochastic process would map e.g. $\Omega \to \mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$, where $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ is the set of all functions $f: \mathbb N \to \mathbb R$.

In regards to your Matlab example, the usual interpretation given to that is that you have drawn 5 independent samples from a normal distribution, i.e. 5 realizations of the random variable. On the other hand, if you define $A = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$, then you could say that you have a random process:

$X: \Omega \to \mathbb R^A$ ($\mathbb R^A$ is the set of functions $f: A \to \mathbb R$). $n_2$ then is just one realization of this random process (not five!), but if you project this process you indeed get 5 normally distributed random variables. Thus e.g. $n_2[1]$ can be interpreted in the following 2 ways:

1) It is the realization of the random variable $X_1$, i.e. of this projection of the random process, i.e. $X_1(\omega) = n_2[1]$.

2) The realization of the random process yields a function $n_2:A \to \mathbb R$, in other words $X(\omega) = n_2$. And $n_2[1]$ is then just the value this function takes when evaluated at 1.